# How can I add QR code as image from OLEobjects in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to generate QR code in Excel file. And, it is success to generate QR code as OLEObject.
However, I can't change this object to image.
Could you please review my code? why it is not change from oleobject to image?
When I run this, a empty image was attached.

```
Dim xObjOLE As OLEObject
Dim ObjName As String

    On Error Resume Next

Set xObjOLE = Sheet1.OLEObjects.Add("BARCODE.BarCodeCtrl.1", Width:=80, Height:=80)
xObjOLE.Object.Style = 11
xObjOLE.Object.Value = "test"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ObjName = xObjOLE.Name
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(ObjName)).Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (Enhanced Metafile)", Link:=False _
        , DisplayAsIcon:=False

xObjOLE.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: What Excel version do you use? Why `On Error Resume Next` is necessary? Do you have a special reference to allow this barcode creation?

Comment: I use Excel under Office 365 version. And I just add `On Error Resume Next` with no special reason. And I get code from "https://hkebi.tistory.com/1181".And I don't want use online api. Because I need run this code without internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Sub setQR(inText As String, outCell As String)
    Dim xSRg As Range
    Dim xRRg As Range
    Dim xObjOLE As OLEObject
    Debug.Print "tempImageFullName:"
    On Error Resume Next
    If inText = "" Then Exit Sub
    If outCell = "" Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xObjOLE = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add("BARCODE.BarCodeCtrl.1")
    xObjOLE.Object.Style = 11
    xObjOLE.Object.Value = "Sample"
    xObjOLE.Width = 200
    xObjOLE.Height = 200
    'xObjOLE.Object.Type = 87
    xObjOLE.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
    ActiveSheet.Paste ActiveSheet.Range(outCell)
    ActiveSheet.Range(outCell).RowHeight = qrW
    ActiveSheet.Range(outCell).ColumnWidth = qrH
    xObjOLE.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).